# Constructer Calling order

Tags: c++, constructor

I know when a constructer is being called, then it gets created in the memory, and when it gets out of the block it gets destroyed unless it's static.

Know I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class CreateSample
{
private:
    int id;
public:
    CreateSample(int i)
    {
        id = i;
        cout << "Object " << id << " is created" << endl;
    }

    ~CreateSample()
    {
        cout << "Object " << id << " is destroyed" << endl;
}
};


void fuct()
{
    CreateSample o1(1);
    static CreateSample o2(2);
}

CreateSample o3(3);
void fuct2(CreateSample o);

int main()
{
    fuct();
    static CreateSample o4(4);
    CreateSample o5(5);
    fuct2(o5);
    return 0;
}

void fuct2(CreateSample o)
{
    CreateSample o6 = o;
}
```

and my concern is in object `o5`, why it's getting called once and gets destroyed 3 times?

Comment: Add a copy constructor and see its constructed more than once... You are basically breaking the "Rule of 3/5" although the only side effects you see of this are your own confusion.

Comment: You are passing a copy to `func2`, you are then making another copy when creating `o6`. Create a copy constructor, and print out when it's called, and you will see.

Comment: If you have disassembled this code, I think you didn't write here such a question. Though people also have already answered to your question, but it seems you don't want to close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateSample o5(5);` calls the constructor `CreateSample(int)`. `fuct2(o5);` and `CreateSample o6 = o;` call the implicitly-defined default [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) `CreateSample(CreateSample const&)`. All three of these variables (`o6`, `o`, and `o5`) call the destructor `~CreateSample()` when their scope is exited.

The fix is to follow [the rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and also define a copy constructor and [copy-assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment):

```
class CreateSample
{
// ...
    CreateSample(CreateSample const& o) {
        id = o.id;
        cout << "Object " << id << " is copy-constructed" << endl;
    }
    
    CreateSample& operator=(CreateSample const& o) {
        cout << "Object " << id << " is copy-assigned from " << o.id << endl;
        id = o.id;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

[Demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/1P375fcq5)

Answer (score 4):

When you wrote `fuct2(o5);` you're calling the function `fuct2` and passing the argument **by value**. This means a copy of the argument will be passed to the function using the **implicitly defined copy constructor**. Thus you get the 2nd destructor call corresponding this object `o`.

Moreover, in `fuct2` you have `CreateSample o6 = o;` which will also use the implicitly defined copy constructor to create `o6`. Thus you will get a third call to the destructor corresponding to this `o6`.

---

You can confirm this for yourself by adding a copy ctor as shown below:

```
class CreateSample
{
//other code here
public:
    
    CreateSample(const CreateSample&obj): id(obj.id)
    {
        std::cout<<"Copy ctor called"<<std::endl;
    }
};
```

And the output you will get is:

```
Object 5 is created            <------ctor called for o5
Copy ctor called               <------copy ctor called for parameter o
Copy ctor called               <------copy ctor called for object o6
Object 5 is destroyed          <------destructor called for o6
Object 5 is destroyed          <------destructor called for o
Object 5 is destroyed          <------destructor called for o5
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/9jGGfXRr5)

---

Though in this particular example you don't strictly require a custom copy constructor or a custom copy assignment operator, they may be needed in other situations. Refer to [the rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: You should mention that normally, when a custom destructor is created, the copy constructor should be defined or deleted.

Comment: @Sebastian Read carefully [the rule of three/five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). In particular it says that: *"If a class **requires a user-defined destructor**, a user-defined copy constructor, or a user-defined copy assignment operator, it almost certainly requires all three."* Note that this is different from your claim where you're saying *"when a custom destructor is created"*. This means that in this particular example the copy constructor is **not strictly required** according to the rule of three.

Comment: Of course not in this example, but the OP clearly did not know the Rule of 0/3/5, but starts to create destructors. So I think it is good to give a note.

Comment: @Sebastian Added the note in my updated answer mentioning that in this particular example they are not required but in some other situations they may be needed/required.